# Gedmo Slug from relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, slug

I use Doctrine ORM and Gedmo\Slug and i have class with related entitty job with title field and i want generate slug by job title. I'm configured SlugHandler like this:

```
/**
     *
     * @Gedmo\Slug(handlers={
     *      @Gedmo\SlugHandler(class="Gedmo\Sluggable\Handler\RelativeSlugHandler", options={
     *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="relationField", value="job"),
     *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="relationSlugField", value="title"),
     *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="separator", value="-"),
     *      })
     * }, fields={"slug"})
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true, nullable=true)
     */
    private $slug = '';


    /**
     * @var Job
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Job", inversedBy="estimation")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="job_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable = false)
     */
    private $job;
```

But in slug field setting title value exactly the same as the title field value (without lowercase, separators and with spaces).
I don't understand what's the matter

Answer (score 0):

If you suddenly encounter a similar problem, you need set option urilize in true:

```
/**
     *
     * @Gedmo\Slug(handlers={
     *      @Gedmo\SlugHandler(class="Gedmo\Sluggable\Handler\RelativeSlugHandler", options={
     *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="relationField", value="job"),
     *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="relationSlugField", value="title"),
     *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="separator", value="-"),
     *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="urilize", value="true"),
     *      })
     * }, fields={"slug"})
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true, nullable=true)
     */
    private $slug;
```